# Try to analyze the given function is convex , non-convex, concave or non-concave?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, complex-numbers, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

The function is given as follows:
$\hat{\mathbf{b}}^{H}\left ( \boldsymbol{\theta} \right ) = \left ( \mathbf{b_{u}} + \mathbf{A_{u}}diag \left ( \mathbf{d_{u}} \right )\boldsymbol{\theta} \right ) \left ( \mathbf{b^{H}_{d}} + \mathbf{\boldsymbol{\theta}}^{T}diag \left ( \mathbf{d_{d}} \right ) \mathbf{A^{H}_{d}} \right ) = \hat{\mathbf{b}_{u}}\left ( \boldsymbol{\theta} \right )  \hat{\mathbf{b}_{d}}^{H}\left ( \boldsymbol{\theta} \right )  $ , where all are fixed except $\boldsymbol{\theta}$

Now the main function is $ P= \left \| \hat{\mathbf{b}}^{H}\left ( \boldsymbol{\theta}   \right )\mathbf{v} \right \|^{2}$ is convex , non-convex, concave and non-concave ?? Here, I am trying to calculate the hessian for 2 variable (Not general case). But in general, how to determine the convexity of the given function? Please help me this regard? Why not general solution to verify convexity of this type of functions rather than trail and error methods?

Where,
$ \mathbf{A_{u}} \in \mathbb{C}^{M_{r}\times N}$ ,
$ \mathbf{b_{d}} \in \mathbb{C}^{M_{t}\times 1}$,
$ \mathbf{A_{d}} \in \mathbb{C}^{M_{t}\times N}$,
$ \mathbf{d_{d}} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$,
$ \mathbf{b_{u}} \in \mathbb{C}^{M_{r}\times 1}$,
$ \mathbf{d_{u}} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$ ,
$\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{C}^{M_{t}\times 1}$,
$\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}$

Comment: P is neither convex nor concave for N > 1.

Comment: Sir, what is the proof that P is neither convex nor concave for N>1?? Please explain in detail if possible

Comment: It shouldn't be hard for you to find the needed counterexamples for N = 2.

Comment: Same thing I have mentioned in the question that without taking specific order like 2 or 3, is there any general proof for the convexity?

Comment: Read https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Comment: Sir, there is no specific example in that textbook. Plz explain sir

Comment: Read the first few chapters.